# Which one is Cost Effective Azure webjob using cron or Logic app?.And Azure webjob Free or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-devops, azure-webjobs

I am using scheduler web jobs in azure.But I am bit confused with its price.Because some site says azure web jobs are free but by keeping it in 'Always On' may affect the price some other says.I want to know which one is cost effective with low price.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebJobs don't cost anything beyond the cost of the WebApp they're part of.
The use of the Azure Scheduler is separate from WebJobs, and this does have an additional cost

As i look at it, if using a continuous job, which doesn't not need the scheduler at all.

WebJobs "always on" which is only for Standard Website, this will make sure your Website and WebJob are always up (won't be the case for free/shared websites), so you can experiment using free but for full usage you need standard plan.

Comment: I'm not sure how valid this is. I saw a message today when configuring web jobs that after the limit of 3 pricing will begin.